# django - eliminating duplicate related items

Tags: django

Here's a snippet from my application:

```
class PortolioItem(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(...)
    ...

class Contract(models.Model):
    ...
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market)
    ...
```

You can see that a User has the same number of PortfolioItems as the number of different contracts he owns.

I want to email users who have any "contracts" of a specific "market" in their portfolios. And I want to email a user only once, regardless of how many different types of contracts of that market he may own. Here's what I do:

```
#get users that want to receive notices
users = User.active_users.investment_notices_users()
#get portfolio items for a specific market
market = Market.objects.get(pk=1)
portfolio_items = PortfolioItem.objects.filter(contract__in = market.contracts.all(), user__in = users)
```

Since a user can have different types of contracts of the same market, the queryset may contain a user for more than once. I can eliminate duplicate users in several ways (an easy solution seems to be: queryset-->list-->set-->list), but wonder if I am at an inefficient/non-elegant solution and there can be a better ORM way that will give me a unique User queryset.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `investment_notices_users` some kind of manager? Might be helpful to see how it's defined.

Comment: yes, it is fairly basic, returns users that have the relevant boolean field set true: 
return self.filter(userprofile__receives_investment_notices=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the users, then the best thing is to start off with the User table:

```
users = User.objects.filter(portfolioitem__contract__market=market)
```

Comment: Does this mean that we can filter using a related set? That was what I was looking for and was not aware of its existence. Is there anything in the ORM docs that mentions this?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Look here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships